# Change Cell Color of Excel using VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, colors

Hello guys i really need your help i've been searching everywhere and literally tried every methode on the internet to change the color of my cells but nothing works can anyone give me the right way to do it this is part of my code and the way that i tried to change the color :

```
Dim cell As Excel.Range
cell = worksheet.Cells(m, l)
cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
```

thank you so much in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error with what you have or it just doesn't do anything?

Comment: @ACCtionMan thank you so much for taking from your time to answer the question . when compiling the programme it doesn't show any error but it also don't do anything on the excil file

Comment: May I suggest adding an error trap and getting the error to display in a message box.  Could you also list what else you have tried.  I did a Google search for 'vb.net excel cell background color' and it had lots of advice, including mentioning that you need to create a Style object.  I don't have anything setup to test it with at the moment.

Comment: I literally tried everything on the 2 first pages of Google hhh  even the one suggestion to make a style what i don't get is how they make the changes happen in the excel file

Comment: If you didn't try with Error trapping, I would suggest that approach.